# Stuck in deadlock when calling multiple task without await keyword

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

Using EntityFramework Core, following code stuck in deadlock on **var details** line but if I put await with SumAysnc() extension method on **var ratingTask** line or use other async extension method (e.g ToArrayAsync() ToListAsync()) then code work perfectly, Is this is a issue of SumAsync() or I am doing it wrong ?

```
var ratingTask = (from f in Db.Table<Feedback>()
                  where f.StoreId== storeId && f.IsDeleted
                  select f.OverallRate).SumAsync();

var details = await (from s in Db.Table<Store>()
                     join a in Db.Table<Address>()
                     on s.AddressId equals a.Id
                     where !s.IsDeleted
                     select new StoreViewModel
                     {
                         s.Id,
                         s.Name,
                         s.IsActive,
                         a.StreetName,
                         a.RegionName,
                     }).FirstOrDefaultAysnc();

details.Rating = await ratingTask;
```

*I am using Ef-Core version 2.0.1 in .Net Framework 4.7 class library*

Comment: Is `detail` different object of is it just a typo?

Comment: Oops, it just a type

Comment: Can you confirm that it's actually a deadlock, and not an exception that is getting lost?

Comment: yeap, it's a deadlock, no exception is getting lost i have tried it with await keyword and with other Async method too and work perfectly except the above case

Comment: Is your connection string allowing multiple active result sets?

Comment: Yes my connection string allows multiple active result sets

Comment: EF's `DbContext` is not thread safe.  Even if your connection allows multiple active result sets, there's a lot of internal housekeeping going on in the `DbContext` to track your entities when you read data, in case you call `SaveChangesAsync` later.  Try using a second instance of the context to perform one of the queries.

Comment: but why in just case of using SumAsync() ??

Comment: "but why in just case ..." - the result of threading errors are unpredictable.

Comment: So it looks like a bug of Entity Framework Core...

Comment: Because you are letting the query for details start before the query for rating has completed. At this point your code is executing in two different threads that can potentially access shared state on the DbContext. Although some of the internal query code in EF Core can handle this by serializing query execution, there is shared state in DbContext that can get corrupted depending on when the actual queries are completed.

Comment: As a general rule, you should await every time you start an async operation on a DbContext instance before you invoke any other API on that same DbContext instance.